# Integrate over a piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I want to calculate the indefinite Integral of

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 2x\cos(\frac{1}{x})& \text{ if } x\ne 0  \\ 
 0& \text{ if } x=0  
\end{cases}.$$

I use the following code:

```
F[x_] := Piecewise[{0, x==0}, {2*x*Cos[1/x], x != 0}];
Integrate[Piecewise[{{0, x == 0}, {2*x*Cos[1/x], x != 0}}], x]
```

It doesn't evaluate. I don't know why it doesn't evaluate the piecewise function.

Maybe this is quite simple  question, but it's not easy for me, a  greenest amateur.

Comment: You are missing a pair of curly brackets in your `Piecewise` expression. Try `Integrate[Piecewise[{{0, x == 0}, {2*x*Cos[1/x], x != 0}}], x]`

Comment: @m_goldberg:Oh,I am sorry,I reedit it again.The question still  remains unresolved.

Comment: Your use of `Piecewise` is still incorrect. Look closely at my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Plugging in

```
  F[x_] := Piecewise[{ {0, x == 0}, {2*x*Cos[1/x], x != 0}}];
   Integrate[F[x], x]
```

leads to the output

```
Piecewise[{{2 (1/2 x^2 Cos[1/x] + 1/2 CosIntegral[1/x] - 
       1/2 x Sin[1/x]), x <= 0}}, 
  I \[Pi] + 
   2 (1/2 x^2 Cos[1/x] + 1/2 CosIntegral[1/x] - 1/2 x Sin[1/x])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = Piecewise[{{2 x Cos[1/x], x != 0}}]
Integrate[f, x, Assumptions -> x != 0] // Simplify

(* CosIntegral[1/x] + x (x Cos[1/x] - Sin[1/x]) *)
```